# Evaluation order of double assignment

Tags: c++

I've found something in our codebase that, even if it has never failed, doesn't look "right" to me.

I've trimmed the code down to something akin to a linked list (the data structures are much more complex than that).

```
Node * node = firstNode();

while( moreNodesAwaiting() )
{
    Node * newnode = giveMeAnotherNode();

    node = node->next = newnode ; // <-- This is what I don't like.
}
```

I'm not sure if undefined behaviour applies here. We're modifying both the data structure and the pointer to it between sequence points, but that's not the same as modifying the value twice.

Also, if the compiler can evaluate elements of an expression in whatever order, does it mean that it can evaluate *node->next* BEFORE the assignment takes place?

Just in case, I've changed it to something like:

```
    node->next = newnode ;
    node = node->next    ;
```

which also emphasizes the fact that we traverse the list.

Comment: This code is legal, well-defined, and horrible.

Comment: @JohnDibling I agree on the horrible part. The embarrashing part is that it may even be that I wrote it years ago.

Comment: We've all written code we'd like to purge from the logs at some point.

Comment: @DiegoSánchez Unless you can look at your own old code and feel embarrased, you haven't learned anything since then. That would be *really* embarassing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assignments associate right-to-left. In other words:

```
a = b = c;
```

is parsed as

```
a = (b = c);
```

and this order is guaranteed by the standard.

That is, for primitive types, it will assign `c` into both `b` and `a`. For non-primitive types, it will call `a.operator= (b.operator= (c))`.

Comment: Just to make it clear: if `a`, `b` and `c` are more or less complex expressions (e.g. involving function calls), the compiler can evaluate them in any order.  It must _evaluate_ the second assignment before the first _for value_ (the side effects can occur in any order), since it needs this value as an argument to the first assignment: the value results of an assignment are the value which has been assigned (with the target type of the assignment).

Comment: In other words, the *assignments* are well-ordered, but the evaluations of the subexpressions `a`, `b` and `c` is not.

Comment: (E.g. `go_to_jail() = reboot() = win_lottery();`)

Comment: Thanks. That was what I suspected, but I wanted to know for sure.

Comment: In `x = y = z;` aka `x = (y = z);`, we can label the two assignments as `a0` and `a1` from left to right.  Then we have `(y,z) before (a0,a1)`, and `(x,a1) before (a0)`, and `(x,y,z,a0,a1) before ;`.  That, and individual functions will not be interleaved, is about it?